# Creating an IONIC Project without using sudo [MacOS]

Tags: macos, ionic-framework

I am facing problems everyday where i have to create a project using sudo and then when i add plugins or cocoapods it gives errors related to root users. How to add permissions that will be set once and for all and i don't have to use sudo for every action.

Answer (score 0):

> How to add permissions that will be set once and for all and i don't have to use sudo for every action.

**This is a *very* bad practice and poses huge security concerns!**

Anyone could have you install a specific malevolent package that could make changes or even even downright harm your system, steal information, etc.

You usually only need sudo to add packages globally. For adding them per project, which is what you usually do, you don't need sudo.

For example to create a new Ionic project, as you are asking in the title, you have to run in your terminal:

`ionic start myNewProject tabs`

and you don't need sudo for that.

I strongly suggest you let the system ask you to authenticate yourself whenever it needs elevated privileges.